# Get values using input()

Tags: python, function, input

I'm trying to make a program that takes the length and width and print the for each observation.

I have this:

```
length = 0 
 width = 0

def GetValues():
    print("Lengt", i+1)
    length = int(input())
    print("width(m) ", i+1)
    width = int(input())
    return length,width

print("How many times")
Times = int(input())

for i in range(Times):
   GetValues()
   Area = length(i)*width(i)
   print('The area :', Area)
```

But i get TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: Please consider using the naming conventions from the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/). This makes it easier for other programmers to read your code.

Comment: @ElenaAlexeenko This code doesn't get any value from the `GetValues` function. The function returns the tuple `(length, width)`, but the return value is ignored by the caller.

Comment: @MatthiasMy bad, next time ill do it better!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Here is the solution**

```
length = 0 
width = 0

def GetValues():
    print("Lengt", i+1)
    length = int(input())
    print("width(m) ", i+1)
    width = int(input())
    return length,width

print("How many times")
Times = int(input())

for i in range(Times):
   length, width = GetValues() # extract return values from function
   Area = length*width # just multiply them
   print('The area :', Area)
```

Comment: consider explaining what's the issue with simon code & How your counter solution solves error got by simon

Comment: I think the problem is that i just called the function, but didnt saved the values on the variables

Comment: you got it simon